# How Do I Modify a Member Variable of Struct in Binary File in C

Tags: c, struct, file-io, io, fread

Structure:

```
typedef struct file {
    char name[20];
    int size;
    int offset;
} file;
```

Structure of Binary File:

```
number of files --> 4 bytes
file structs --> 28 bytes each
content of files --> <offset>
```

I want to update the offsets for the files in my structs that are in the binary file. This is my implementation of it:

```
int writeOffsets(char *archiveFile, file list[]) {
    FILE *binFile;
    int numFiles;
    file index[MAX];

    binFile = fopen(archiveFile, "wb+");

    fwrite(&numFiles, sizeof(numFiles), 1, binFile);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        while (fread(index, sizeof(file), 1, binFile) == 1) {
            fseek(binFile, -(sizeof(file)), SEEK_CUR);
            printf("For Offset\n");
            printf("before %d\n", index[i].offset);
            fwrite(list, sizeof(file), 1, binFile);
            printf("after %d\n", index[i].offset);
        }
    }

    fclose(binFile);
    return 0;
    
}
```

However, when I look at my binary file, most of the contents were deleted. How do I currently get to the location and modify the offset member variable?

Comment: `numFiles` is not initialized. `sizeof(file)` is unsigned, so `-(sizeof(file))` could be a large positive number, check that. *"number of files --> 4 bytes"* Do you mean 4 counts? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you aware that you are always reading in the same `index[0]`, and always writing the same `list[0]`?